# We are committed to rolling up the evil county lines drugs gangs

Tags: phrase-meaning, british-english

UK Prime Minister Boris Johnson said the following on the issue of rising crime in the UK:

> "We are committed ***to rolling up*** the evil county lines drugs gangs. . . . which predate on young kids and send them to die in the streets to feed the cocaine habits of the bourgeoisie."

Does *"to rolling up"* mean "to defeat"?

Source: [PM Boris: ‘Bourgeoisie’ Cocaine Users Fuelling Killing of Children on Streets of Britain](https://www.breitbart.com/europe/2019/10/02/pm-boris-bourgeoisie-cocaine-users-fuelling-killing-of-children-on-streets-of-britain/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary. one meaning of *roll up* is

> to increase or acquire by successive accumulations.

But its hard to connect the phrase with MW's definition.

A second meaning of the verbal phrase is to reduce something (e.g., roll up the maps, roll up the papers). From Collins

> If you roll up your sleeves or trouser legs, you fold the ends back several times, **making them shorter**.

I have a feeling that Prime Minister Boris Johnson used *"rolling up"* figuratively (meaning from Collins) to mean that his administration is committed to reducing/curbing the number of *evil county lines drugs gangs*. He intends to do this by *"hiring 20,000 new police officers to patrol the streets."*

Comment: Yes. To reduce or compact.

Answer (score -1):

I have assessed this question with a focus on British English because your quotation is from the British Prime Minister.

I did initially think you had either misheard the word *rounding*, or that Prime Minister Boris Johnson from whom you were quoting had made a characteristic gaffe:

> We are committed to *rounding* up the evil county lines drugs gangs.

This is a *common* expression and would make a lot more sense. "Rounding up" idiomatically means *to gather in or bring together*. It was historically used to describe the herding of cattle but now is commonly used to describe catching criminals.

"Roll up" has several *common* idiomatic uses but none that would fit this context. However, it has been pointed out to me that this expression is sometimes used to refer to catching criminals in a similar way to the expression "rounding up".

I do not believe it is widely used in British English as I have *never* heard it before now, and have only been shown a small handful of news headlines using it and as yet have not seen this definition in any British English dictionary. I suspect that it is a phrase "borrowed" from American English.

So it would seem that the quotation means to catch, get rid of, or in a sense "defeat" the drugs gangs.

Comment: Actually, 'rolling up' might make sense in this context; it usually implies that the process will be a possibly protracted one in which a few low-level 'easy pickings' will be arrested and interrogated, and the information garnered by such interrogations used to get some slightly-higher-level people, and so on until the enforcement establishment has gone as high as it can.

Comment: In UK usage one can 'roll up' gangs of criminals, spies, terrorists, etc. The expression evokes the idea of starting at one end of something and dealing with it progressively until the other end is reached.

Comment: Does the use of "drugs gangs" bother any of you like it bothers me?

Comment: "Drugs gangs" does not bother me at all; it is a common way of referring to gangs of criminals who specialise in supplying illegal drugs, at least in the British media. "Drug gangs" might also be seen. Why does it 'bother' you? Do 'fraud gangs' and 'robbery gangs' bother you too?

Comment: Note that in the UK criminal justice system, 'drugs' (plural) can be used to denote a type of criminal offence or charge - a drugs charge, a drugs conviction, a drugs enquiry, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think it bothers me because of the plural form "drug**s** gangs". I am just not familiar with that term I guess - I have mostly heard "drug gangs". Well, "robbery gangs" does not bother me at all, but I certainly won't feel confident in writing "robberies gangs". Oh, can you take a look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drugs+gangs%2Cdrug+gangs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrugs%20gangs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrug%20gangs%3B%2Cc0), please?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey From the Ngram, it seems like "drugs gangs" in comparison to "drug gangs" is not common usage even in British English. Is the usage more common in speech?

Comment: 'Drugs' is a category of crime. Try the 'drugs charge, drug charge' Ngram for British English between 1990 and 2000. Possibly 'drugs gang' is more common in speech, and in the type of publication (e.g. newspapers) that Google Ngrams does not index.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have never, ever heard of "rolling up" criminals. Nor has Google, check this ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rolling+up+criminals%2Crounding+up+criminals&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crounding%20up%20criminals%3B%2Cc0 Okay, so Boris Johnson has been quoted a saying it, but this is a man known for gaffes.

Comment: Astralbee - You have now - I await your apology - [see here for example](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ACYBGNRZ4WpNUWbbt7OaKixyOgMlCjpdUQ%3A1570388138941&ei=qjiaXbeNOcatgQaI5LDYCQ&q=police+roll+up+gang&oq=police+roll+up+gang&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16630.20376..20662...0.2..0.136.987.0j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i13i30.gxujrpNKIUE&ved=0ahUKEwi3irnZp4jlAhXGVsAKHQgyDJsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) beware of relying too much on Ngrams, which do not index newspapers and magazines, still less speech.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your linked Google search shows no more than 2 examples, neither from a credible British source. They could be bad translations. I'll apologise if you can directly link to another credible British English quotation.

Comment: Not just British - "The suspected Russian spy ring rolled up by the F.B.I. this week" - [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/06/30/world/europe/30spy.html) 29 June 2010 - "Feds roll up East County drug networks" - [San Diego Union-Tribune](https://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/courts/story/2019-09-19/feds-roll-up-ast-county-durg-networks) 19 September 2019

Comment: "Scots officers rolled up the gang in October 2012 in raids in north Liverpool, Glasgow, Greenock and Renfrew." Scottish Daily Record, 17 October 2014

Comment: "Hitler insisted that German strategy be one of using the panzerforces to roll up the Allies from the east." - [Imperial War Museum](https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/the-german-response-to-d-day)

Comment: "and then turn south to roll up the rest of the Federal lines as far as he could" - [Lee's Last Retreat: The Flight to Appomattox
By William Marvel, page 10](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NhDTYdSop5gC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=roll+up+escape+line&source=bl&ots=t3qN7OKxro&sig=ACfU3U0Rp5_iMBiWVrh8a_5EYthuQmN-7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ0u_SsIjlAhUClFwKHdnZAfgQ6AEwJHoECCwQAg#v=onepage&q=roll%20up%20escape%20line&f=false)

Comment: @AIQ About "drug**s** gangs": It sounds very odd to me too, but that is because I use American English. I'm surprised no one is mentioning this difference between US  and British (+ maybe others?) usage. "Drug**s** laws", "drug**s** charges", etc.  vs. US singular: "drug laws" & "drug charges".

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be a UK English thing, although the section of a UK police force responsible for drug or drugs crime is usually called the "drug squad", possibly for pronunciation reasons, although some newspapers call them 'drugs squads'.